# Installed Sage Package but coundn't use

Tags: package, sage

I want to use the spkg 'coxeter3', and I installed it successfully because it shows up under "installed_packages()".

[code and spkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3XmY.png)

Here's my code:

```
def MuL(C):
    W = CoxeterGroup(C, implementation='coxeter3')
    List=[]
    for u in W:
        U = (W(v) for v in W.bruhat_interval(u, W.long_element()))
        next(U)
        for v in U:
            ldiff = v.length()-u.length()-1
            if is_even(ld):
                p = W.kazhdan_lusztig_polynomial(u, v)
                if p[ld//2] != 0:
                    List += [[u,v]]
    return List
```

(ref: http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001143)

I run' MuL(["A",4]) ' for example:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACLj.png)

what should I do to fix it?

Note:

mac os

spkg was installed not in terminal using (!sage -i coxeter3)

I used Jupiter to run the code but the same error appears using shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is due to not having rebuilt SageMath after installing the package.  Going into your Sage directory and running

```
./sage -b
```

to rebuild should rectify this (`make` probably will also work).

Once you get past this, you also have a typo; you should replace `ldiff` with `ld` (or vice versa), as at the findstat link you provide.  After doing so, I get (from `MuL(["A",4])`) the following:

```
[[[], [1]],
 [[], [2]],
 [[], [3]],
 [[], [4]],
 [[1], [1, 2]],
...
 [[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [[2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [[2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]]]
```

which seems likely to be what you are looking for.  Good luck.